# Use link to add text to inout box

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a table of Codes and Prices.

The "codes" are set as a link -

CODENUMBER

I have a form with the text box

When the link in the table us added I want the code to be added to the input field.

This actually works great:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('a').click(function(){
$('#text_tag_input').val($('#text_tag_input').val()+$(this).html()+', ');  
$('#code').val($('#code').val()+$(this).html()+', ');
});

});//]]>  

</script>
```

But the site I am using a wordpress templated site that includes jquery 1.10.2 and the 1.7.1 is causing some of the "bits" of the site not to work so need the "onClick" action to work with 1.10.2 - or any other solution.....

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this one use on event

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
    $('#text_tag_input').val($('#text_tag_input').val()+$(this).html()+', ');  
    $('#code').val($('#code').val()+$(this).html()+', ');
});
```

Comment: Tried scrip added exactly as below:   but still no population of the text box.... <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

    $('a').on('click',function(){
    $('#text_tag_input').val($('#text_tag_input').val()+$(this).html()+', ');  
    $('#code').val($('#code').val()+$(this).html()+', ');
    });

    </script>

Answer (score 0):

There are no issues with the version of jQuery you are using. Check out the code in the fiddle. Try and change the version of jQuery to see the results. More code and examples of your problem might help...

```
$('a').click(function(){
   $('#text_tag_input').val($('#text_tag_input').val() + $(this).html() + ', ');   
   $('#code').val($('#code').val()+$(this).html()+', ');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c6Q88/1/